# Text file type that supports in-line notes

Tags: file, text, citations

The idea is simple: A text file that supports attaching additional text as notes (or tags or comments) to parts (sentences or words) in the main text body. I would like to apply such a file type specifically in a simple application for viewing research work, so that citation can be attached in-line to sentences or phrases within a work. I mean, has anybody come across such? Has that wheel been invented already? even if in a rudimentary fashion or as part of a larger non-proprietary file type.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for XML. There was a DTD called TEI for Text Encoding Initiative but I remember it from many years ago, so it might not be popular or standard. https://tei-c.org/

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow; this is a site for *programming* questions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html for a description of how you can use Pandoc with the Markdown format. Pandoc allows you to either link to, or embed, citation metadata in Markdown files through a YAML header. It also has a syntax for referencing these items to generate citations and bibliographies. http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html is a bit denser but describes the various options in more detail.

Comment: I'll check it out